# /Mappings/Index is found but not /Mappings with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, resources, url-routing

Just struggling with a simple issue with ASP.NET MVC. I have a list of views, each view associated with an Index.aspx view being associated by default with /MyView.

Yet, for some reason I have 1 view named /Mappings that does not work (404 resource is not found) whereas the explicit path /Mappings/Index works.

I have the default route settings as provided by the default ASP.NET MVC sample

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
);
```

And, the default Index works for the other views of the same webapp.

Any idea what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define default action if it is not provided:

```
route.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}", // URL with parameters
            new { action = "Index" }  // Default action if not provided
        );
```

**EDIT:**

Look at this link:

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx

You can use this debugger to test your routing.

Comment: Thank, but unfortunately, my default route is defined. It works with the other views as well. Just one that does not.